# Angularjs directive for bootstrap datepicker plugin

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using [this bootstrap daterange](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/markup.html#date-range) component at my webpage. But, I have to put it with angular way. I don't know angular well. That's why, I have tried to search angularjs `directive` for that plugin. It seems that I can't find the exact one at online. Is there any available directive for that plugin?

Thanks in advance

[JQuery demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1tmgqbX9rXwB9Hkkp4rA?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using this directive:
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: I don't find date-range option at there :(